# SSRS Split expression #Error

Tags: reporting-services, split, expression, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Trying to get this expression working:

```
IIF(Fields!Text.Value like "*som:*",Split(Fields!Text.Value, ": ").GetValue(0)&":" & vbcrlf & Split(Fields!Text.Value, ": ").GetValue(1), Fields!Text.Value)
```

And for the fields which contain "som:" it works as I want but not for the "else fields" which show #Error. I've also tried Fields!Text.Value.ToString().Contain("som:") but got the same result.

The Warning goes: The Value expression for the textrun ‘XXXXXX.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Index out of matrix/range (trying translate it so sorry if the error message is not exact)

The expression is made on a textbox and I need to have this function cause our costumer requires it.

I want this input kinda:

*TExt text text som:*

*text text text*

and else

*TExt text text text text text*

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use custom code:

Report ► Report properties ► Code    *(Report is on the toolbar on the TOP)*

Add below code:

```
Function Valid(ByVal str As String) As String
    If (str.Contains("tom:")) Then
        Return str.Split(":").GetValue(0) + ":" + vbCrLf + str.Split(":").GetValue(1)
    Else
        Return str
    End If
End Function
```

user like this: "=Code.Valid(Fields!Text.Value)"

Comment: Could you explain how this works? Kinda new to this :)

Comment: I think IIF in reporting service is like, no matter the condition is right or not, both actions (true & false) will be executed.

Comment: You can right click blank area of your report, and you can see the "Report Properties", click it to add custom code.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Just one more tiny question:  How do i get an "enter" after ":" so that value(1) goes under value(0)?

Comment: try this : str.Split(":").GetValue(0) + ":" + vbCrLf + str.Split(":").GetValue(1)

Comment: I updated the answer, please remark as answer if it is working. Thanks